# How to read a fixed number of bytes from a c++ std::istream

Tags: c++, iostream

How to read a fixed number of bytes from a `std::istream` without doing any extraction? For example, I have a variable `sz` of type `size_t` and I would like to read `sizeof(size_t)` bytes from the `istream`.

```
void foo(std::istream& is) {
  if(is.rdbuf()->in_avail() < sizeof(size_t)) return;
  // how to read to sz from istream is without extraction (advancing pointers)
  size_t sz;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean when you say "without doing any extraction"? what about the read method? is it applied to your "without doing any extraction"?

Comment: 'Fix-byte data' is meaningless. Please don't invent your own terminology.

Answer (score 1):

You can only `peek` the next character without extracting.

As such, you should change your strategy: instead of trying to avoid extraction, extract the characters that you need, and then restore the state of the stream. That is possible if the stream supports seeking:

- use `tellg` to get the current position
- extract the bytes
- use `seekg` to jump to the earlier position

Otherwise, you may need to implement a buffer of your own to do whatever you're trying to achieve by "reading without extracting".