# How to read specific number of bytes from istream into a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, istream

I'd like to read a number of bytes from an `istream` into a `vector`. I thought [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780054/how-to-read-a-fixed-number-of-bytes-from-a-c-stdistream) would have the answer but it's actually asking an entirely different thing.

My code so far:

```
std::vector<char> read_buffer(std::istream& is, const std::size_t size) {
    std::vector<char> buf;
    buf.reserve(size);
    is.read(buf.data(), size);
    return buf;
}
```

This doesn't work because `vector` was written into without it knowing, so after the `is.read`, its size is still 0, not `size`. What's the proper way to implement this function?

Comment: Use [resize()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) not [reserve()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve).

Comment: Well, if you know that you are reading in chars, couldn't you just read in a certain number of characters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43681922/vectorreserve-cause-vector-iterator-offset-out-of-range

Comment: reserve is just allocating memory: it does not set the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vector container wraps a dynamic array. It is important to understand the difference between capacity and size of a vector.

**Size:**
The size of a vector is the number of items it is currently holding.

**Capacity:**
Capacity is the number of items the vector can hold without requiring a memory reallocation.

The array which the container wraps can be larger than the number of elements it contains. When you push back a new element, the vector will add it to the end of the array. If there is no room left,  i.e: capacity was already equal to the size before before pushing, the vector requests for a larger array.

In your code,  you have used `reserve` which is used to increase the capacity of the vector. The size of the vector remains zero.

To increase the size of the vector, you should use `resize`.